# How to handle illegal latitude exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on elastic search and in my index I have one geo_point data type.When I am indexing latitude greater than 90 it is throwing illegal latitude exception .I found it should be in range -90 to +90.But I am not understanding how to handle if latitude exceeds 90.I am using elastic search 5.4.Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you index your data? Can you show some code?

Comment: PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "text": "Geo-point as an object",
  "location": { 
    "lat": - 99.8569,
    "lon": -71.34
  }
}